# How to restore previously released phone number using Twilio API?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

By following this [article](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223183028-Cancel-or-release-a-Twilio-number), I released a Phone Number using Twilio API by submitting an HTTP DELETE request to the IncomingPhoneNumber REST API Resource and it succeeded, but now I cannot purchase it back using Twilio IncomingPhoneNumber API. I want to dynamically repurchase back the number using Twilio API and not using console.

Note: I am using node version: 16.20.2 and Twilio library version: 3.72.0

After releasing the number, using the same number I tried to purchase the number back using the Twilio IncomingPhoneNumber resource but got an error:

Expected: purchased successfully and should have got a new sid for that number.

Got: RestException [Error]: +12059557580 is not available.

Here is the code which I use to purchase a number:

```
exports.purchaseNumber = async (number, voiceSid) => {
  try {
    //we can pass voice application sid
    let status = await client.incomingPhoneNumbers.create({
      phoneNumber: number,
      voiceApplicationSid: voiceSid,
      smsApplicationSid: voiceSid,
    });
    return status;
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.code == 20404) {
      throw { message: lang.NUMBER_NOT_FOUND, statusCode: FAIL };
    }
    throw error;
  }
};
```

And here is the code to release the number:

```
exports.deletePhoneNumber = async (id) => {
  return client.incomingPhoneNumbers(id).remove();
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality is, as of now, only available in the Console and not via API. Sorry.

> By using Console, you can restore numbers that you released in the past 10 days. Release numbers will show up on Console's [Released Numbers page](https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/restore). Simply click on the **Repurchase Number** button to provision the number back to your project.
> [Docs](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223183108-Restoring-a-previously-released-phone-number)

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the reply.